# Center radio button below label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to center the `Radio Button` below it's `Label Text`.
This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908281/center-radio-button-below-label).
But the difference is my radio button and its label is getting rendered from `C#` at runtime. So it gets rendered as,

```
<tr>
 <td>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="my_radio_button_id" />
<label for="my_radio_button_id">My Label</label>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 ...    
</tr>
```

so the `RadioButton` gets rendered first and then the `Label` that's why I can not use the given answer for that question. So tried a lot with `CSS` but was unable to come up with any applicable `CSS`.

SO, As per I know I can achieve this using 2 way's

1. Use jquery to manipulate the Rendered `Html`.
2. Override the`RenderContents` method to render the data As I need.

But I was wondering if there is any way to do this using `CSS` only(Or small use of jquery/javascript). So I dont have to go through one of the above approach.

In case of confusion feel free to comment.

Comment: replaced input and label, http://jsfiddle.net/yqn7n296/ . It seems placed center

Comment: Centering these two elements to one another is going to require a context...basically a parent element. What is the parent element?

Comment: @hm_ngr I don't have control over in which order the controls get rendered. SO i can not just change there order.

Comment: @Paulie_D Parent element is `<tr><td>` it gets rendered in table

Comment: Use it in a table ..tr for radiobutton and another tr for label ..and center the td contents

Comment: Both are inline element so you can use vertical-align: middle property.

Comment: Depending on your broswer support requirements, flexbox can do that. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

Flexbox [**Suppport**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is IE10 and up

```css
td {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .25em;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="my_radio_button_id" />
      <label for="my_radio_button_id">My Label</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want css solution then you can try something like this.

```css
.r{
    top: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}
.rp{
   width:90px;
   position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="rp">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="my_radio_button_id" class="r"/>
  <label for="my_radio_button_id" class="l">My Label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: I want radio heading and then radio button below that heading

Answer (score 1):

Cool! Enjoy

```css
.checkboxgroup {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkboxgroup label {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.checkboxgroup [type="radio"] {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="checkboxgroup">    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="my_radio_button_id1" />
      <label for="my_radio_button_id1">My Label1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxgroup">    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="my_radio_button_id2" />
      <label for="my_radio_button_id2">My Label2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxgroup">    
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="my_radio_button_id3" />
      <label for="my_radio_button_id3">My Label3</label>
  </div>
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/uyLrx06a/)

Comment: Hope! you will be satisfied and no need to go for flex.