# How to center radio button with label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radiobuttonlist

For almost 1 hour now I try to center my radio button with a label which seems to be needed . I tried all now , but no effect so far. Any help would be appreciated , but I tried really a lot so far.

```html
<div class="col-md text-center custom-control custom-radio">
    <input autocomplete='off' type="radio" class="custom-control-input"  
          th:id="some id" th:name="${testcase.id}"  > 
    <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="some id">Label</label>
</div>
```

It is inside a div class="row" and in this specific column marked with col-md I want just my radio button to be centered

Comment: check my solution with the radio replacement...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908281/center-radio-button-below-label if you mean center one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Put a **br** tag between **input** and **label**
Set input tag related css class, specific width: 25px; (depend on label text)

```css
.custom-control-input {
width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md text-center custom-control custom-radio">
    <input autocomplete='off' type="radio" class="custom-control-input"  
          th:id="some id" th:name="${testcase.id}"  > 
    <br>
    <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="some id">Label</label>
</div>
```

Now check this, You want to center like this

```css
.text-center{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md text-center custom-control custom-radio">
        <input autocomplete='off' type="radio" class="custom-control-input"  
              th:id="some id" th:name="${testcase.id}"  > 
        <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="some id">Label</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: why should I put <br> between radio and label. That would be a line break. I do not want this.

Comment: You tell center with a label, Center what?

Comment: re-edited code look the second one

Answer (score 0):

here is a workaround with a div.falsecheck that replace the real radio button:

```css
.falsecheck {width:20px; height:20px; border:1px solid #ccc; margin: auto; border-radius:10px}
.custom-control-label::before {
  display:none !important;
  visibility: none;
  opacity:0
}
label {text-align:center}
input[type="radio"]:checked+.falsecheck {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md text-center custom-control custom-radio">
  
     <label class="custom-control-label" th:for="some id">
      <input autocomplete='off' type="radio" class="custom-control-input"  
          th:id="some id" th:name="${testcase.id}"  >
          <div class="falsecheck"></div>
     Label</label>
      

</div>
```